# Grub not appearing

Tags: linux, grub2, dual-boot, grub, grub-legacy

When I turn on the PC the GRUB screen doesn't display and goes directly to any OS (which is configured on the F2 boot start list) and when I tried to find the /etc/default/grub file it's missing there.

I am using dual boot with Windows 11 (default from my PC). I would like to know how to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have grub installed? Windows used to overwrite grub on some updates, but I think that was happening more in the past. Lately, that should be not happening any more.

The minimum I would put in /etc/default/grub is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
```

You can adjust the default to your preferences. The first in the grub menu is numbered 0, then 1,... Timeout, you can also change to your preferences. It means the number of seconds it will wait your input before it will boot the default OS.

Then run `sudo update-grub`. That command will actually run `grub-mkconfig` (`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) which will create `grub.cfg`. However, if grub is not started at the boot, that will most probably not help. Then find some guide to reinstall grub. Here is one: https://www.fosslinux.com/115031/troubleshoot-boot-problems-by-reinstalling-grub-on-linux.htm

Try also `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` for more information.

Comment: I always had Grub installed before but it didn't appear anymore, Now I realize that a few times that I pressed F10 the GRUB appeared after the boot screen... I needed to create a brand new grub file which I didn't have on /etc/default with your minimum values as you guided and after I typed on terminal sudo update-grub I faced an error message. I have tried to reinstall grub from this site but when I type: ```grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p4``` (my disk) it appears: ```grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.```

Comment: It seems you do not have installed everything you need. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/784990/grub-2-install-error-grub-install-error-usr-lib-grub-i386-pc-modinfo-sh-does